# Visual Studio - How to find string equals evaluations in vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need to convert a bunch of VB.NET code to C#.  Instant C# is a great helper but one area... string case-insensitive VB.NET code.

Ahead of conversion, I would like to find a way to search for the VB.NET code that does string equals evaluations and change them to use String.Compare(x,y,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)=0.

**Is there a way in Visual Studio 2017 to find these string evaluations? Maybe leveraging .NET Compiler Platform SDK?**

For example Test routine would be changed like representative of Test2 routine then converted to C#.

```
Option Compare Text
.
.
.
      Private Sub Test()
        Dim x as string = "x"
        Dim y as string = "y"

        If x = y then msgbox("They match")

      End Sub

      Private Sub Test2()
        Dim x as string = "x"
        Dim y as string = "y"

        If String.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) = 0 then msgbox("They match")

      End Sub
```

C# converted output below

```
  private static void Test()
  {
    string x = "x";
    string y = "y";

    if ((x ?? string.Empty) == (y ?? string.Empty))
    {
      MessageBox.Show("They match");
    }

  }

  private static void Test2()
  {
    string x = "x";
    string y = "y";

    if (string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("They match");
    }

  }
```

**While the original question has not been answered, the NEED to answer it has been rendered moot given that the latest Instant C# creates case insensitive output.  Below is the output of Test routine.**

```
  private static void Test()
  {
    string x = "x";
    string y = "y";

    if (string.Equals(x ?? string.Empty, y ?? string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
      MessageBox.Show("They match");
    }

  }
```

Comment: Contact us directly Dave - I think we can implement this very quickly.

Comment: VB.Net string comparison is case sensitive, so I don't really understand what you're trying to do

Comment: If this question is about how to find/replace string comparisons using the `=` operator with `String.Compare` in VB.NET, then this really has nothing to do with C#, correct?

Comment: Option Compare is fairly tricky, just blindly changing the comparison is going to produce subtle bugs on empty strings.  Looks to me you'll be much better off doing it after the conversion, those wonky `?? string.Empty` expressions are pretty easy to find back in source.  But they are easy to find back in the IL, pops up as Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareString.  The ildasm.exe utility can provide the IL dump to search through.

Comment: @GuillaumeB. It's not case sensitive when Option Compare Text is used.

Comment: @RufusL I can see that perspective. i'll remove the c# tag.

Comment: @HansPassant "..blindly changing the comparison is going to produce subtle bugs on empty strings."  Agreed. I chose to keep the question focused on finding the points in code with a single example.  Ultimately you are correct an evaluation of the change does need to occur once the code is in focus.

Comment: @DaveWilliamson - Please install the latest build of the converter - this is handled properly now for Option Compare Text.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas It may have been handled properly before. I'm not making a statement regarding that. However, I did pull down the latest (says june 22 in about) and it throws in a "trin" that certainly throws compiler errors to point it out but I'm not sure that was your intent.

Comment: From MS Docs "You should not use the String.Compare method to test for equality (that is, to explicitly look for a return value of 0 with no regard for whether one string is less than or greater than the other). Instead, to determine whether two strings are equal, use the String.Equals(String, String, StringComparison) method."

Comment: @Mary I'll update the post accordingly.

Comment: @DaveWilliamson - Install again - the combination of the strict string comparison option with the Option Compare Text was a problem.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas That fixed the "trin" issue.  Although I'm not sure you want the String.Compare in your general purpose converter.  I'm only using String.Compare as an example. I haven't done a set of extensive sample evaluations to see if it holds true.

Comment: @DaveWilliamson - String.Compare does the best job at being the equivalent to case-insensitive comparison using less than or greater than operators, while the Equals instance method with OrdinalIgnoreCase should be preferred when determining whether 2 strings are equal (as Mary pointed out).  The next build recognizes this.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Ran a quick test and while String.Compare comes close it fails when comparing empty string and null string.  Something like this seems to pass. String.Compare(String1 ?? String.Empty, String2 ?? String.Empty, true) == 0

Comment: @DaveDoknjas and as you have probably implemented the Equals equivalent also holds up for string empty and string null.  String.Equals(String1 ?? String.Empty, String2 ?? String.Empty, AnyOneOfTheIgnoreCaseStringComparisons)

Comment: @DaveWilliamson - There's a compromise in source code conversion - at some point you have to adjust to the C# way of doing things, and that doesn't include every single one of the myriad of weird rules that VB uses (just some of them).